# Hibernate best way to define data types (Object/Primitive) in mapping class

Tags: hibernate

I'm working on Struts2 with hibernate 3.3. When I did reverse engineering of my tables from oracle DB i got all table number fields of table mapped in class with BigDecimal,Long,Boolean etc., All are mapped as Objects not as primitive data types like(long,boolean etc). Now in this case I'm not getting any problem. But what i'd like to know is when number of users of my website increases and doing more actions will it cause JVM out of memory issue? Should i change mapping variable names to primitive types?

Comment: How many users are we talking? How big is the data structure? Why don't you load test it and find out? The issue with using primitive types is that they cannot be `null` so what happens when the value is `NULL` in the DB?

Comment: yeah u r right. When the field is not null i can use the primitive type. The reason why i asked like that is i'm new to this environment.

Comment: Should upgrade the hibernate to the latest version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use a primitive type if the column is not nullable, and a wrapper object if the column is nullable.

You shouldn't choose the type of a field depending on the memory it uses. You should choose it based on what you need to store in the field.